# What is the purpose of variable duplication in a method?

Tags: java

I see this [below] all over in the Android code (and some other code sources). What is its point or purpose?

```
class Foo {
    int mBar = 1337;

    static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(isFubar());
    }

    boolean isFubar() {
        int ret = mBar; // <--- Focus of attention

        if (ret == 666)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

It seems like a waste of time and resources. mBar clearly isn't being modified. There is no risk of it being modified (in the given context), so why would one duplicate the primitive just to preform a noninvasive check on it and return?

EDIT Specific example from the class CellLayout in the Android Source

```
public void cellToRect(int cellX, int cellY, int cellHSpan, int cellVSpan, RectF dragRect) {
        final boolean portrait = mPortrait;    <--- Here it is
        final int cellWidth = mCellWidth;
        final int cellHeight = mCellHeight;
        final int widthGap = mWidthGap;
        final int heightGap = mHeightGap;

        final int hStartPadding = portrait ? mShortAxisStartPadding : mLongAxisStartPadding;
        final int vStartPadding = portrait ? mLongAxisStartPadding : mShortAxisStartPadding;

        int width = cellHSpan * cellWidth + ((cellHSpan - 1) * widthGap);
        int height = cellVSpan * cellHeight + ((cellVSpan - 1) * heightGap);

        int x = hStartPadding + cellX * (cellWidth + widthGap);
        int y = vStartPadding + cellY * (cellHeight + heightGap);

        dragRect.set(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }
```

Comment: Can you point to a specific example?

Comment: I don't know, but I would look at the history and see if there was possibly a version where it mattered.

Comment: Maybe the developer just hates the "m wart".  But seriously by making a copy and making the copy final, s/he's indicating that this method doesn't modify the field.

Comment: @DavidV that would make sense. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @DwB would you prefer `mBar = 8008`? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps for multi-threading. If the value of mPortrait changed between the following two lines you would have mixed results.

```
final int hStartPadding = mPortrait ? mShortAxisStartPadding : mLongAxisStartPadding;
final int vStartPadding = mPortrait ? mLongAxisStartPadding : mShortAxisStartPadding;
```

For example:

```
final int hStartPadding = true ? mShortAxisStartPadding : mLongAxisStartPadding;
// somehwere else: mPortraint = false
final int vStartPadding = false ? mLongAxisStartPadding : mShortAxisStartPadding;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas come to mind.

1. The expression needed to retrieve the class member variable might be really complicated (your example is not), so saving it in a local variable might be more readable.
2. It is possible that storing it in a local variable is more efficient, especially if the method has to access the value more than once. (Your example does not do this.)
3. Retrieving the value once gets its value at that moment in time, and not some later value that another thread may have modified in the meantime.
4. Storing it in a local variable makes it easy to examine with a debugger.

For your particular example, only reason (4) makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I use it so i can modify the variable in recursion or loops and not mess with the original one. It also helps with passing the variables between classes and other methods.

Also, if it is changed while the method is running, the method will not mess up, it will continue with the variables it started with. I had this major problem while multi-threading my graphics printing and code. The code would change variables and weird stuff would happen on the screen.

I don't know about hardware or speed, but on the code side, it makes it very simple and flexible in many cases.

Comment: To your first response, I agree IF the variable was being modified at all. To the second, That only matters for objects. Primitives are pass by value, so it doesn't matter if the exact variable is passed.

Comment: I agree, it was the only explanation i can think of. I edited my answer remembering the previous problems i had. Notice it is calling global variables, not the variables sent to the method.